# Where to store parameters for ajax request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a application with many data-tables. Each table have a sorting and filters.
Request to API looks like this:

```
axios.get('path/to/api/users', { params: {
  sort: {
    byField: 'name',
    orderBy: 'DESK'
  },
  filters: {
    status: 'active',
    country: 'spain'
  },
  search: 'pablo'
}});
```

And structure of my state looks like this:

```
entities: {
  users: {
    byId: {
      0: {},
      1: {},
    },
    allIds: [0, 1]
  },
  posts: {
    byId: {
      0: {},
    },
    allIds: [0]
  }
}
```

I have a question: where a should store a `params` object for each table?
In container (`this.state`) or in another reducer? Or in url query string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely keep the filtering/sorting/paging data along with the data in the store (under a parent object/reducer).

This information is often displayed - the current page, the sorting order, filter terms and so on will probably appear in the UI anyway.

Furthermore, this information is cohesive with the data itself, that is, they change together. When you fetch more pages, the last fetched page is updated along with the last page data. It makes sense to keep them together.

The query string can then be built from this data.

*Update: "How to better structure the reducer?"*

Well, as I said, I'd keep the data and metadata together in some parent object. Something like this:

```
const myReducer = (state = {
    data: {...}, 
    metadata: {
        paging: {...}, 
        sort: {...}, 
        filters: [], 
        search: ''
    }
}, action) => ...
```

This way, the data and metadata change together, while their structure can change independently, if such a structural change is needed.

Edit: LRU consideration

If you would like to keep N versions, you'll need to store them in an LRU implementation that is immutable. If you can find one (or make one), then here's how you would use it:

```
const myReducer = (state = {
    versions: new ImmutableLRU()
}, action) => ...
```

The reducer body then sets the object structure into the LRU however it is used. Could be something like:

```
return {...state, versions: versions.put(JSON.stringify(metadata), data)};
```

This sets the LRU key to be the value of the metadata properties, and you can look up a cached result accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with you. But the question remains how to better structure the reducer?

Comment: I've added some info on how to structure the reducer.

Comment: The proposed structure does not involve storing multiple versions of the params object. Every time the params object changes, it will be necessary to make a request to the server. Am I right or not?

Comment: You are correct. Why would you need to store multiple versions of the params? Caching purposes? How would you cap the amount of memory that this structure consumes?

Comment: I think this is not a problem if i apply an algorithm like LRU for example and save `n` versions of `params` object

Comment: Then the data modeling would have to support that. Added.

Comment: I was looking for an implementation of `ImmutableLRU` but I found nothing. Your answer is the most exhaustive. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I personally think this should be part of the URL.
This way each state can be represented as unique URL which is good for SEO and can be shared to directly link to the specific filter / sorting.

Comment: Yes, but when i pass to the page by link inside the application i must fetch data one more time, because i not save query string in some data-store. Although one can combine storage in query params and this.state or redux storage.

Comment: Maybe this would give you some idea how to approach it: https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-updating-the-state-with-the-fetched-data

Comment: In this case `filter` is a simple string so its can be used as a key in reducer `idsByFilter`. In my case `filter` more difficult, it is object and i understand how use object as a key? Or how make better structure my store?

Answer (score 1):

I keep all of my entities together in an entities reducer, and then have separate reducers per feature.  So you will have 3 reducers: entities, users, and posts.  Assuming you will have separate sorting/filters per feature, I'd organize it something like this:

```
entities: {
  users: {
    byId: {
      0: {},
      1: {},
    }
  },
  posts: {
    byId: {
      0: {},
    }
  }
}

users: {
  allIds: [0, 1],
  sort: {
    byField: 'name',
    orderBy: 'DESK'
  },
  filters: {
    status: 'active',
    country: 'spain'
  },
  search: 'pablo'
}

posts: {
  allIds: [0],
   sort: {
    byField: 'date',
    orderBy: 'DATE'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest 3 things here:

1) Keep params as a part of URL. It will create a unique URL for specific filter/ sorting which will be helpful for SEO.

2) Maintain a reducer called paramsReducer which will will be updated on change of any filter and sorting. 
InitialState of params could be the default state you want.

```
const paramsInitialState: {
  sort: {
    byField: 'name',
    orderBy: 'DESK'
  },
  filters: {
    status: 'active',
    country: 'spain'
  },
  search: 'pablo'
}

export default function paramsReducer(state=paramsInitialState) {
switch(action.type){
//case for update params
}
}
```

3) On mount of parent component update the params state to use it in other component if required.

Also entities state could be normalized:

```
entities: {
  users: {
    0: {},
    1: {},
  },
  posts: {
    0: {},
  }
}
```

No need to store allIds under users and posts as keys under users and posts state. It will reduce the memory consumed by your application. If you need allIds in your application then better to derive this from the state saved at the container level.

For reference see this link [Goomo.com](https://www.goomo.com/hotels/search?amenities=&checkin_date=2017-12-24&checkout_date=2017-12-25&city_name=Mumbai&filter_hotel_id=&filtered_h_n=&hotel_id&hotel_name&locality_id&locality_name&location=2898&location_id=12738&page_no=1&page_size=50&place_name=Mumbai%2C%20India&price_per_night=&rooms=%5B%7B%22adults_count%22%3A2%2C%22children_age%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%5D&sort=price_per_night%2Cdefault&star_rating=&ta_rating=&total_price=). Here filter, sorting implemented using URL and state is also maintain for the filter applied.

Comment: Proposed structure is cool, but how to sync url and `params Reducer`? And remains a problem with versioning of the object `params`,  every time the params object changes, it will be necessary to make a request to the server.

Comment: If you are making server side filtering and sorting then on each change you can update query string with new params and then make a new server call.

Comment: And for client side filtering just update the query string with new params no need for server call.

Comment: Yes but i can cache data on the client, to reduce the load on the server

Comment: If i update query string and not call a server i don't know what data need to show now, because i not store ids of data for each `params` object

Comment: I think when sorting and filter is changed you just need to implement some client side logic to update the data. But Can you explain me overall flow you are expecting it will be helpful.